# How to use React.hydrate when using vue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Bit of an odd situation here - I have a website written in Vue and I want to demo a library I've written in react. I can avoid server side rendering (SSR) by wrapping `ReactDOM.hydrate(ReactApp, document.getElementById('react'area'))` but I don't want to do that. I want to render everything SSR, but I don't see how it's possible.

Here is my `renderOnServer.js` for vue:

```
process.env.VUE_ENV = 'server'

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const filePath = './App/dist/server.js'
const code = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8')

const vue_renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createBundleRenderer(code)

//prevent XSS attack when initialize state
var serialize = require('serialize-javascript')
var prerendering = require('aspnet-prerendering')

module.exports = prerendering.createServerRenderer(function (params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const context = {
        url: params.url,
        absoluteUrl: params.absoluteUrl,
        baseUrl: params.baseUrl,
        data: params.data,
        domainTasks: params.domainTasks,
        location: params.location,
        origin: params.origin,
        xss: serialize("</script><script>alert('Possible XSS vulnerability from user input!')</script>")
      }
      const serverVueAppHtml = vue_renderer.renderToString(context, (err, _html) => {
        if (err) { reject(err.message) }
        resolve({
          globals: {
            html: _html,
            __INITIAL_STATE__: context.state
          }
        })
      })
    })
});
```

So basically I'm configuring SSR above to read `server.js`:

```
import { app, router, store } from './app'

export default context => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    router.push(context.url)

    router.onReady(() => {
      const matchedComponents = router.getMatchedComponents()

      if (!matchedComponents.length) {
        return reject(new Error({ code: 404 }))
      }

      Promise.all(matchedComponents.map(Component => {
        if (Component.asyncData) {
          return Component.asyncData({ store, context })
        }
      }))
        .then(() => {
          context.state = store.state
          resolve(app)
        })
        .catch(reject)
    }, reject)
  })
}
```

and `server.js` above is just looking for the right vue component and rendering. I have a test react component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class ReactApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>Hihi</div>
      )
    }
  }
```

and my vue component:

```
<template>
  <div id="page-container">
    <div id="page-content">
      <h3 class="doc-header">Demo</h3>

      <div id="react-page">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
<script>
  import ReactApp from './ReactApp.jsx'
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

  export default {
      data() {
          return {
          }
      },
  }

  ReactDOM.hydrate(ReactApp, document.getElementById('#react-page'))
</script>
```

But obviously it won't work because I can't use document in SSR.

Comment: have you read this documentation https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html ?

Comment: i dont see how to use that with react. if you can... there's a bounty

Comment: Have you tried importing your custom react library on your vue component and registering it ?

Comment: yes its a bit harder than that

Comment: `React.hydrate` is not intended to be run on the server.  The Vue component which is rendering the React component would need to either call `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` or call `React.hydrate` on the client.  Calling `hydrate` can be done in `mounted()`.  You would need to do this in a way so that `ReactDOMServer` is not a dependency for your wrapper so it is only in the server code.  You can use dependency injection to provide this to your app on the server.  Then if it is provided, you use it, if not, you call `React.hydrate`.  You still need to connect state and such though.

Comment: A note on this... a simple application that does SSR is a bit more complex than simply something that you posted here.  Without having a working example (at least doing the Vue SSR) it would take a lot of effort to "give" an answer that actually works in that situation.  Primarily, you have to `hydrate` the Vue app as well when doing SSR.  Simply rendering it to a string is not the same as having it running on the page (it is just the same rendered DOM with no event handling). https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html

Comment: You need to add the ID or some other selector to the app's root element yourself or the app won't hydrate properly

Comment: Please upload your reproduction on GitLab, GitHub or BitBocket. I can help you but you should give me a sample of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the purpose of [hydrate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate) is to match react DOM rendered in browser to the one that came from the server and avoid extra render/refresh at load.

As it was pointed in the comments `hydrate` should be used on the client-side and React should be rendered on the server with [`renderToString`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring).

For example, on the server it would look something like this:

```
const domRoot = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <StaticRouter context={context}>
      <AppRoot />
    </StaticRouter>
  </Provider>
)
const domString = renderToString(domRoot)

res.status(200).send(domString)
```

On the client:

```
<script>
  const domRoot = document.getElementById('react-root')

  const renderApp = () => {
    hydrate(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <AppRoot />
        </Router>
      </Provider>,
      domRoot
    )
  }

  renderApp()
</script>
```

Technically, you could render React components server-side and even pass its state to global JS variable so it is picked up by client React and hydrated properly. However, you will have to make a fully-featured react rendering SSR support(webpack, babel at minimum) and then dealing with any npm modules that are using `window` inside (this will break server unless workarounded).

SO... unless it is something that you can't live without, it is easier, cheaper and faster to just render React demo in the browser on top of returned Vue DOM. If not, roll up your sleeves :) I made a [repo](https://github.com/maxgram/react-saga-universal) some time ago with react SSR support, it might give some light on how much extra it will be necessary to handle.

To sum everything up, IMO the best in this case would be to go with simple `ReactDOM.render` in Vue component and avoid React SSR rendering:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="my-compiled-react-bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  function init() {
    ReactDOM.render(ReactApp, document.getElementById('#react-page'))
  }
  init();  
</script>
```